# CartThrob errors in EE CP under PHP 7.0

Tags: cartthrob

I'm using CartThrob v2.71 (the last available v2.x?) on EE v2.11.7 (the latest available v2.x) under PHP 7.0 (just upgraded) and now getting CP errors:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: 8192
Message: Non-static method Cartthrob_mcp::module_enabled() should not be called statically
Filename: cartthrob/mcp.cartthrob.php
Line Number: 264 [...and 251...]
```

Any suggested fix for this or am I being a cheapskate by not upgrading both EE and CartThrob to v3...?

Answer (score 0):

Following the comment in the file, this seems to be a fix to remove the errors (though I don't use the Subscriptions addon):

*/system/expressionengine/third_party/cartthrob/mcp.cartthrob.php*

line 240:

```
    /*
    // EE chokes in template publishing with any CT tag on _validate when we're loading ct payments lib
    $EE->load->library('cartthrob_payments');

    if ($EE->cartthrob_payments->module_enabled('subscriptions'))
    {
        self::$nav['subscriptions_settings'] = array('subscriptions_settings' => '');
    }
    */

    $EE->load->library('cartthrob_payments');

    // if (self::module_enabled('subscriptions'))
    if ($EE->cartthrob_payments->module_enabled('subscriptions'))
    {
        self::$nav['subscriptions_settings'] = array('subscriptions_settings' => '');
    }       

    $modules = array(
        'Cartthrob_order_manager'   => 'om_sales_dashboard',
        'Ct_admin' => 'order_admin',
        'Cartthrob_item_options' => 'global_item_options',
    );

    foreach ($modules as $key => $module)
    {
        if ($EE->cartthrob_payments->module_enabled($key, NULL))
        // if (self::module_enabled($key, NULL))
        {
            self::$nav['modules'][$key] = array( $key => $modules[$key]);
        }
    }
    return self::$nav;
```